# Retrieve database records by comparing time field to current time and current time plus 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I have a database table used to store bookings which uses a time field(bookingTime) and a date field(bookingDate). 
I am trying to view records for the next hour by comparing the time field(bookingTime) to CURTIME. I get some results returned but not everything. I have tried to use NOW() and interval but nothing seems to return the correct results. The results do not show me a full hour of bookings and don't seem to go over the hour mark meaning it will show me a booking at 13:59 but not 14:01.

Here is the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT
    TIME_FORMAT(bookingTime, '%H:%i') as bookingTime, 
DATE_FORMAT(bookingDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as bookingDate, 
jobId, callSign, name, pickupAdd, phoneNum, destAdd, jobType, carType 
FROM job 
WHERE TIME(bookingTime) between curtime(bookingTime) and curtime(bookingTime)+3600
order by DATE(bookingDate), TIME(bookingTime) asc
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE statement is full of errors. `CURTIME()` only returns the current time and does not take any parameters. You want to use `TIME()` to get the time portion of a timestamp. You also need to use `INTERVAL` to add time to a timestamp. You also need to compare the booking time to now/now+1 hour.

Try this:

```
WHERE TIME(bookingTime) between CURTIME() and CURTIME()+INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  AND DATE(bookingDate) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: I had tried to use TIME() but it returns results over multiple dates and won't just give me results for today. Do I need to include bookingDate in the where clause? thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks John, that worked. Spent a LONG time trying to get this working.